# To find number of complete cases in a data frame and make a new data frame with the number of such complete cases from each file

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to get the number of complete cases for a given data frame and show them in the form of a data frame with id and nobs(number of complete cases for a particular id) as columns. Till now I got the answer for id's which are single numbers like 10, 23, 45 etc but for set of numbers like c(2,3,4,5) but I am getting the sum of all the lengths of each number in a set while printing for all the numbers. So I want to know where am going wrong. Below is my code.

```
`complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332){

 file_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)

 tmp <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(file_list))
 for (i in seq_along(file_list)) {
 tmp[[i]] <- read.csv(file_list[[i]])
 }
 output <- do.call(rbind, tmp)

 complete <- output[complete.cases(output),]


 d<-data.frame(id,nobs=length(which(complete[,"ID"] %in% id)))
 d
  }`
```

Thanks

Comment: When you use `do.call(rbind,tmp)` you are binding *all of the tables read in so far* together. So the number of rows in `output` is the total number of rows (excluding incomplete cases).

Comment: Isn't this a Coursera question?

Comment: @ananda yes, are u too taking the course?

Comment: @RajaRaghudeepEmani, No. I recognize the question from earlier questions at SO. Please search around and if you still can't answer, edit your question showing where specifically you are stuck.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I am stuck when m calling a set of numbers as ids, for eg id= c(2,4,5,6) for this I am not getting a desired data frame where i need complete cases of individual id's but rather getting sum of all the results of individual id. For single digit id like id=45 or id =3 am getting the correct data frame, problem is only when it is set of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This hasn't been tested so it really belongs in a comment, but it's just a bit too long.

Try this:

```
## not tested
directory <- "...directory with your files..."
nobs   <- sapply(list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE),
                 function(file) sum(complete.cases(read.table(file))))
result <- data.frame(id=seq_along(nobs),nobs)
```

I have a feeling this will produce the result you want with much less code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code but when I ran it didnt get the desired output. The output I want is number of complete cases with respect to an ID. I have example results ( https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdoc%2Fcomplete-demo.html). From my code I got results for single numbers but not for a set of numbers, I feel there some problem in forming my data.frame or I should run a loop....am stuck with it.